# allocate a tie between a job and a terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

How can I allocate a tie to the currently open terminal?
Sorry - to make clear:
As I mention in this question
https://superuser.com/questions/575847/kill-running-script-i-think-i-must-allocate-terminal
I am having trouble when I run commands on a another machine using ssh and here-doc.  i.e.
ssh another_machine << 'ENDSSH' commands/script-to-run ENDSSH
but I get this message:
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
This creates a problem that being now the job/process cannot be detected/killed with ps/job commands.

Can I tie the job to a currently open terminal or new terminal window?

Thanks a lot!

FYI:
I am using the other question (linked above) only as one example of when I need to allocate a tie.  I expect others to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `ssh` the `-t` option, which forces it to create a pseudo-terminal.

Comment: hey sorry that didn't work. I'll paste some output just to make sure I am not doing anything silly.